# Finding IntegerPartitions[252] with no zero and no duplicates

Tags: code-request, number-theory, memory, number-representation, partitions

Well, I am trying to execute the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 252;
k = 7;
f[x_] := Select[Min[Counts[Flatten@x] /@ #] > 1 &]@x;
f@Select[DuplicateFreeQ[#] && FreeQ[#, 0] &]@IntegerPartitions[n, {k}]
```

Which finds the `IntegerPartitions[252]` (and there are $269232701252579$ partitions for that specific number) and delete the solutions that contain a zero or two or more times the same number in the solution. But my code keeps crashing, I think because $269232701252579$ is too big.

I have one question:

Is there a way to execute the above code without the crash?

Comment: For exactly 3 numbers try `IntegerPartitions[10, {3}]`.  The online documentation for `IntegerPartitions` has more details.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I see. I edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "no zero"?  `IntegerPartitions` doesn't produce any zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's faster to construct the partitions with no repetitions directly instead of constructing all partitions and then eliminate those with duplicates:

```
n = 252;
k = 7;
a = Select[IntegerPartitions[n, {k}], DuplicateFreeQ]; // AbsoluteTiming
b = # + Range[k - 1, 0, -1] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n-k*(k-1)/2, {k}]; // AbsoluteTiming
a == b

(*    {63.0103, Null}    *)
(*    {32.3662, Null}    *)
(*    True               *)
```

In this case the construction of `b` took about half as long as `a`. The difference may be even more pronounced for larger sets.

Also, by doing the application of `# + Range[k - 1, 0, -1] &` in a more efficient way, or finding a way to avoid it, you can further increase speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And how can I delete the solutions that use numbers that turn up ones?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: "...that turn up ones", what does that mean?

Comment: Can you take a look at @JimB's answer. Under the 75 seconds there is a explanation what the function $f$ does.

Comment: As @JimB says, only 231 and 230 don't occur twice: `Cases[Tally[Flatten[a]], {x_, 1} -> x]` gives `{231, 230}`. Should be easy to eliminate.

Answer (score 3):

First, generate the sequences without applying `f`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 252;
k = 7;
results = Select[DuplicateFreeQ[#] &]@IntegerPartitions[n, {k}];
Length[results]
(* 49929373 *)
```

This takes about 75 seconds.

It appears that the function `f` selects lists in `results` for which all numbers occur at least twice in `results`.  The numbers to be removed are the ones that only occur once which can only involve the largest numbers and the largest number in this case is 231 = 252 - (1+2+3+4+5+6).  So we can check on the frequency of numbers 231, 230, ..., etc. until the frequency is larger than 1.

`IntegerPartitions` makes this convenient in that the numbers in each list are sorted from high to low, and the lists are sorted by the first element from high to low.

Looking at the first 10 rows in `results` we see

```
results[[1 ;; 10]] // TableForm
```

[image: First 10 rows]

Numbers 231 and 230 only occur once so rows 1 and 2 can be deleted.

```
results = results[[2 ;;]];
```

I'm assuming that getting results specifically for 252 is your objective so something more formal (i.e., not using the "by hand" work) is not necessary.